# Reprompt to open a file using try and except

Tags: python, python-3.x

open_file(): This function takes no parameters, then uses the try-except format to prompt for a filename, open the data file and return the file pointer if successful. Your function should be able to catch the error and print the error message if it fails to open; and then reprompt. It will reprompt

I have written this code but not sure if it is correct and meets the requirements mentioned above. Can anyone please help me?

```
def open_file():
    try:
        fp = open(file, 'r')
        return fp
    except FileNotFoundError:
        fp = open('congress.txt','r')


file = open('congress.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def open_file(max_tries=20):
    tries = 0
    fp = None    # We don't have that yet
    while not tries or not fp:  # While the file is not loaded (or we haven't tried)
        tries += 1 # One more try
        try:       # Try to load it
            fp = open(input("enter a filename : "))
        except FileNotFoundError:   # Oops  
            print("file not found")  # We should tell the user about that
            if tries > max_tries: break  # We shouldn't go into an infinite loop
        except IsADirectoryError:   # Oops  
            print("file is a directory")  # We should tell the user about that
            if tries > max_tries: break  # We shouldn't go into an infinite loop
    else: return fp      # When you got the fp, return it
    pass # If you didn't get it run the code here (maybe raise an exception)
    # If you don't raise an exception, it will return None
```

Comment: Not broken anymore, I forgot to initialise fp

Comment: Better, but it's It's still not pep 08 compliant. And since it's obviously an homework assignment, you shouldn't post a full coded answer.

Comment: Tell me why it isn't PEP8-compliant and I will delete my answer if you want

Comment: `if tries > max_tries: break` and `else: return fp`. And I'm not asking you to delete your answer, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an assignment so I won't post a full-blown solution, but I can at least answer the explicit questions: your code obviously doesn't meet the requirements - it doesn't prompt for another file name if the first one is not found an doesn't print any error -, now it does something that's not only not required but also totally unexpected - it tries to open some hardcoded filename if the asked one isn't found.

Just a hint: repeting an operation is usually done using a `for` or `while` loop.

Answer (score -1):

I reworked it a bit, but this will do what you want it to do.

```
def open_file():
    try:
        file_name = input("What is the filename? ")
        with open(file_name) as fp:
            new_doc = fp.read()
        return new_doc
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found")
        new_doc = open_file()
        return new_doc


file = open_file()
print(file)
```